# Active admin and Pundit

Tags: activeadmin

I have some difficulties to install Active Admin gem in Rails with Pundit.

In my Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
```

In my active_admin.rb

```
def authenticate_admin!
  redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user && current_user.admin
end
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # [...]
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin!
  # [...]
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  # [...]
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
  # [...]
  config.logout_link_method = :delete
end
```

I have this error when I go to /admin :

```
Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError at /admin
```

I think i have to define a policy but I don't know where. Do you have a good tutorial for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use something like this to verify the policy usage.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index
end
```

ActiveAdmin don't support this checks. You can't configure them in the ApplicationController or you need to skip them for all ActiveAdmin Controllers

Comment: I have this in my ApplicationController :
`include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :devise_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_controller? `

So I have to add something like `unless: active_admin_controller?` ?

Comment: You need something like `unless: :devise_or_active_admin_controller?`

Comment: Thanks ! So I did something like this in my ApplicationController :

`include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :devise_or_admin_controller?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_or_admin_controller? `

and 
`def devise_or_admin_controller?
    devise_controller? || params[:controller] =~ /admin\/.*/
  end`